# how to set an id with some value in of td in javascript

Tags: javascript, html-table

i m creating td in javascript what i want is this `"<td id='abc'>"` how can i set the td id in javascript i use `setAtteribute()` not working

my code look like this

```
var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
             cell4.innerHTML = "Song";
     var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
     cell5.setAttribute('id','example1');
```

i want to set id of the td with value example 
plz help

Answer (score 3):

cell5.id = 'example1';   // javascript

I suppose we're talking about IE here? I don't know about "id", but..

http://webbugtrack.blogspot.com/2007/08/bug-242-setattribute-doesnt-always-work.html

Answer (score 2):

Using `javascript` (w/o jquery)

```
        cell4.id="some_td_id"
```

for example

```
        advTable=document.getElementById("advance_option");
        advRow = advTable.insertRow(advTable.rows.length);
        advRow.id ="tr_id"  // Here you can set tr's id
        cell0=advRow.insertCell(0);
        cell0.id="td_id"  // Here you can set td's id
    cell1=advRow.insertCell(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cell5.attr("id","example1"); //jquery
```

Comment: That wouldn't work, as cell5 is not a jQuery object. The original poster also doesn't appear to be using jQuery, but plain JavaScript.