# CreateElementwithId function dont work

Tags: javascript

Im trying to get a function that writes elements with ID.
but i cant get It work.

this is what i have.

```
function createElementWithId(elementName, idName)
{
    var id = document.createElement(elementName);
    id.idName = idName;
    return id;
}
```

Any ideas ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the id of an element by using `.id` rather than `.idName`.

```
function createElementWithId(elementName, idName) {
  var elem = document.createElement(elementName);
  elem.id = idName;
  return id;
}
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342743/how-to-set-an-id-with-some-value-in-of-td-in-javascript) is another example of someone using `id`.

Comment: aa great! got it work with a class function but not with the ID creator.

thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The **id** should be set as `.id`, not `.idName`

```
var elem = document.createElement(elementName);
elem.id = idName;
```

Answer (score 1):

The [document.createElement](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/dom2.shtml)  will return the element.
And the element have `id` attribute, not idName attribute.

```
function createElementWithId(elementName, idName)
{
    var element = document.createElement(elementName);
    element.id = idName;
    return element;
}
```